# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException. I encountered this exception below, while trying to compile an XAML code

Tags: c#, xaml

> Please can someone be of help. I encountered this exception below, while trying to compile an XAML code
>
> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
>     HResult=0x80131501
>     Message='Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '40' and line position '22'.
>     Source=PresentationFramework
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
>      at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
>      at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
>      at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
>      at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
>      at Master_Page_core.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\deepa\source\repos\Master_Page_core\Master_Page_core\MainWindow.xaml:line 1

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
IOException: Cannot locate resource 'newfolder1/sidebar.jpg'.

[this is the image of error occuring . Click here to see image .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozxIp.png)

> this is xaml code

```
<Grid.Background>
  <ImageBrush ImageSource="NewFolder1/sidebar.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"></ImageBrush>
  </Grid.Background>
```

> I show similar post on this error but it was not helpfull . they asked to include the folder in the project but the Folder containing images is already included in the project.

Comment: Did you set the Build Action of your image to Resource?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer thanks for your reply sir. my issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?
`<ImageBrush ImageSource="NewFolder1/sidebar.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your source code from Visual Studio "View -> Properties" section.
When you will select your `Grid` from XAML, you will be able to go to Properties and choose the ImageBrush source from there:

[image]

It's good if the image file you are mentioning will be listed there. 
Please choose the file from the drop-down and make sure that "Build Action" for the file is set to "Resource" and "Copy to Output Directory" is set either "Copy always" or "Copy ifnewer".